# JavaScript JSON escape security

Tags: javascript, json, escaping

Could someone explain to me why the string inside the JSON executes? (Second `<script>` tag and onwards.)

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZLyve

```js
<script>
    var data = {
      "UserId": "576757ef-1234-4aac-aad8-98f9088138f4",
      "Firstname": "Firstname<script>alert(\"User firstname security!\");</script>",
      "Lastname": "Lastname<script>alert(\"User lastname security!\");</script>",
      "Email": "<script>alert(\"User email security!\");</script>",
      "Username": "Username<script>alert(\"User username security!\");</script>"
    };
</script>
```

The code is a result from converting data to JSON from MVC:

```
var data = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.User));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the *browser's HTML parser* doesn't understand Javascript. All it sees is:

```
<script>
    blah blah blah </script>
    blah blah <script>blah blah</script>
    ...
```

It passes the contents of each of these `<script>` tags separately to a Javascript interpreter.

If you're embedding Javascript in HTML, you'll have to HTML escape it, or you need to break up the `<script>` tags:

```
'</sc' + 'ript>'
```

Comment: A XSS attacker could bypass the //<!-- by simply adding --> before the script then, right?